# Regex parttern to validate the host section of url

Tags: c++, boost, boost-regex, url-validation

I am trying to validate the **host** section of the url, (not the entire url)

so in the case of *http://www.example.com/some/path*, all I want to validate is 'www.example.com'.

I have the following regex, `^((?:&#|[[:alnum:]]|[\-_])(?:&#|[[:alnum:]]|[\-\._~\?#\[\]@!$&'\(\)\*\+,;=])*(?::[0-9]{2,})?)$` and it works well in all cases, (including *http://localhost* and so on).

Looking at https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex, this all works fine except for 'sites' like [http://उद](http://%E0%A4%89%E0%A4%A6)ाहरण.परीक्षा and http://⌘.ws, (are those actually allowed?)

If the given host names are possible, what regex could I use, over and above `[[:alnum:]]` to validate host name like *उदाहरण.परीक्षा* and *उदाहरण.परीक्षा:80*?

Comment: Does it need to be grammatically perfect (say for validation) or can you get away with something simple like: `[^:/]+` for general extraction?

Comment: I don't think it has to be perfect as such, but it has to be fairly robust I would say. Your regex would return true for spaces, and dots as a first character, (to name just a few).

Comment: On the page you linked there are a number of regexes that work for your example, why can't you use those?

Comment: In the past I've generally used the regex documented in the [rfc](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)(see Appendix B.).

Comment: Those regexes are for full url validation, (and are flaky anyway), I just want to validate the host, (and the port), hence the reason I want to know how to match characters like `उदाहरण.परीक्षा`

Comment: @G.M., I saw that RFC, but `[^\/?#]+` would suggest that hosts like `...sss!%^@&(*&(*()(!)@(_+_` are valid, (and it even allows multi-lines).

Comment: @FFMG -- Just to clarify.  The `[^/?#]+` component of the regex captures the `authority` rather than just the `host` and has the general form `[ userinfo "@" ] host [ ":" port ]` which is at least part of the reason it accepts the text you mention.  Hence some more work may be required to identify the `host` only.  However, I do get the feeling this may be sending you down the wrong route anyway...

Comment: @G.M., Yes I agree, (about the authority), but that regex would allow me to capture invalid characters even if I was to put aside the port/user/password.